# Здравствуйте! Как зациклить prompt на проверку? Если ничего не введено или введена не цифра, prompt запрашивает снова

Tags: javascript

```
// Необходимо зациклить prompt на проверку numberOne, mathOperator, numberTwo следующим 
  образом: например ничего не ввели(prompt запрашивает ввода данных), ввели не число(prompt 
  запрашивает ввода числа) и т.д
  Учусь JS, ДЗ выполнил, код ниже, но хочу проверки на каждом этапе ввода данных, пробовал 
  через while, но не получается, видимо не правильно пишу код.... делаю цикл на проверку 
  ошибок const numberOne,выхожу из цикла, создаю константу const mathOperator и код 
  темнеет(((( VS код пишет что предполагалось другое.....




const numberOne = prompt('Ведите первое число');
const mathOperator = prompt('Введите математическое действие');
const numberTwo = prompt('Ведите второе число');


if (!numberOne) {
    console.log('Первое число не указано');

} else if (!numberTwo) {
    console.log('Второе число не указано');

} else if (!mathOperator) {
    console.log('Не введён знак');

} else if (!+numberOne || !+numberTwo) {
    console.log('Некорректный ввод чисел');

 } else if (mathOperator != '+' && mathOperator != '-' && mathOperator != '*' && mathOperator 
    !='/') {
    console.log('Программа не поддерживает такую операцию');
}

switch (mathOperator) {
    case '+': console.log(+numberOne + +numberTwo);
    break;
    case '-': console.log(numberOne - numberTwo);
    break;
    case '*': console.log(numberOne * numberTwo);
    break;
    case '/': console.log(numberOne / numberTwo);
    break;
    default: console.log('Учимся дальше)');
    }
```

Comment: оператор сравнения выглядит так !==, а не !=

Comment: !== строгое сравнение != не строгое сравнение т.е. (5 != '5' false) (5 !== '5' true) не строгое сравнение подразумевает неявное приведение типов

Comment: Вы практически сами описали всё, что нужно сделать, в вопросе: поместите prompt в цикл (например while(hasError)), а в самом цикле устанавливайте переменную hasError в зависимости от ввода пользователя.